# Populate column based on values in another

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table as per the below.

```
|   A   |   B  |
+-------+------+
|  100  |      |
|  #N/A |      | 
|  200  |      |
|  #N/A |      |
|  #N/A |      |
```

What I am trying to do, is to populate the values in column B, based on the latest non error value in column A. As per the table below. I am not sure which Excel function to use, so don't have anything I have tried yet.

Desired result

```
|   A   |  B   |
+-------+------+
|  100  | 100  |
|  #N/A | 100  |
|  200  | 200  |
|  #N/A | 200  |
|  #N/A | 200  |
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A2),B1,A2)
```

and copy downward:

[image]